# Unable to populate Form.CheckBox array programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I’m attempting to replace populating an array (named "_Checks") using hard coded values with programmatically populating the array values. The array elements are CheckBox.name for all of the checkBoxes on a winForm form.

The form has 10 rows of controls with each row's controls' enablement triggered by the state of the leading checkbox. Checking a lower level box “activates” all rows above it and deselecting a higher level box “deactivates” all rows (if any) below it.

The following code is working:

```
private CheckBox[] _Checks;
public PrizeTemplateWRKG() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _Checks = new CheckBox[]
    { LevelCheckBox00, ..., LevelCheckBox09 };  //array population via hard code [10 elements]
}
private void LevelCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int mstrTag = Convert.ToInt32((sender as CheckBox).Tag);
    // logic for identifying checking or unchcking; excluded as irrelevant 
    HandleCheckboxes(mstrTag);
}

private void HandleCheckboxes( int mstrTag)
{
    // wrap following in checking/unchcking logic; excluded as irrelevant 
    for (int x = 0; x <= mstrTag; x++)
    {   _Checks[x].Checked = true;    }
}
```

I initially tried

```
CheckBox[] cbArray = (CheckBox[])Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

which won't complie (error: *Cannot convert type
'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox[]'*)
Then tried:

```
List<CheckBox> cbList2 = (List<CheckBox>)Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

which will compile but throws an exception at run-tiime:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2 [System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox]'.

**TL;DR** I am able to find the checkboxes and create lists of checkbox names (which I intend to convert to an array with ToArray) but regardless of how I format extraction from *Control.ControlCollection* I end up with a string list/array and cannot convert the string to a Checkbox[] containing checkbox names.  The closest I've come is  using the *Converter<TInput,TOutput>* approach trying with both lists and arrays:

```
 _cbList = convrtR.ConvertAll(new Converter<string, CheckBox>(stringTOcheckbox));

public static CheckBox stringTOcheckbox( string slist2cblist)
{   return new CheckBox();   }
```

but the result is an array populated with “System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox, CheckState: 0” elements.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert `IEnumerable` to array or list, you shouldn't use explicit casting. That's what the `ToList` and `ToArray` functions are for.

```
List<CheckBox> cbList2 = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-5.0

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response.  I had actually read the linked page previously but your code helped me make a new mental connection..Thanx.